# Changing a Tableau calculated field into a dimension

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I have a field that is an  approximate sales quantity per month that is called : `[Sales Quantity / Week (Stock Unit)]`.  This field is a one value per product since it is an approximation calculated as:

```
SUM([sales amount]) / [number of weeks]
```

I also have an `[Inventory Value]` for each week of the year for the last 3 year for each products....

I would like to compare on a weekly basis when my Static Average sales for a particular product are higher than the weekly `[Inventory Value]`, as this changes every single week.

Ultimately I want to get the amount of times the `[Sales Quantity / week (Stock Unit)]` value is higher then the `[Inventory Value]`.

Changing my `[Sales Quantity / Week (Stock Unit)]` into a dimension.

Comment: Welcome! To make it easier for people to advise you, make the problem more precise. Provide a small amount of sample data, describe what results you want to see for that sample data, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can't use an *aggregate* calculated field as a dimension, but you can use a fixed LOD calc as a dimension. So you can either remove the SUM() call from your calculated field or add a { FIXED xxx : } around your calculation -- depending on which gets the rigiht effect for you